# formato para numeros con muchos caracteres SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

Hola estoy trabajando con ORACLE 11g realizando una consulta a la tabla a través de sqlplus luego guardo el resultado de la consulta en un log. El problema es que hay dos campos que retornan una cantidad de suma y poseen muchos caracteres por lo que no se ven como notación científica y el otro con #. Que formato le puedo dar para que me aparezcan completamente. Adjunto imagen con resultado de la query. Esta es mi query.sql:

```
SET PAGESIZE 84
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET LINESIZE 80
SET UNDERLINE -
SET HEADING ON
COLUMN ORIGEN HEADING 'ORIGEN'  Format a8
COLUMN TIPO HEADING 'TIPO' Format a20
COLUMN CANTIDAD HEADING 'CANTIDAD' Format a20
COLUMN TOTALSALDO HEADING 'SALDO' Format a20
COLUMN fecha HEADING 'FECHA' Format a20
SELECT DISTINCT a.ORIGEN,DECODE (B.TIPOREGISTRO,'AbonoI', 'BST-ARCHIVO','ARCHIVO')"TIPO", a.TOTALREGISTROS AS CANTIDAD, a.TOTALSALDO AS SALDO, a.fecha
FROM SALDO_USER.REGISTROCONTROL a, SALDO_USER.REGISTROSDETALLE B
WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.fecha),'YYYYMMDD')=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') 
AND B.IDCONTROL IN (A.IDCONTROL)
ORDER BY a.fecha DESC;
EXIT;
```

Donde CANTIDAD Y SALDO son la que necesito modificar para obtener los valores correctos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:
Hay que pasar a char los datos, para esto se debe colocar to_char(a.totalregistros) as cantidad y para el otro campo se debe aplicar lo mismo to_char(a.totalsaldo) as saldo.
Esto es debido a que el tipo de datos number, llegando a cierta cantidad de tamaño redondea a notación científica. Por eso se deben dejar como CHAR.

Saludos